# C# using statement with return value or inline declared out result variable

Tags: c#, using

I am wondering if there is some way to optimize the using statement to declare and assign its output together (when it is a single value).

For instance, something similar to the new way to inline declare the result variable of an out parameter.

```
//What I am currently doing:
string myResult;
using(var disposableInstance = new myDisposableType()){
    myResult = disposableInstance.GetResult();
}

//That would be ideal
var myResult = using(var disposableInstance = new myDisposableType()){
    return disposableInstance.GetResult();
}

//That would be great too
using(var disposableInstance = new myDisposableType(), out var myResult){
    myResult = disposableInstance.GetResult();
}
```

Thanks for your input.

Comment: You could always wrap the entire `using()` in a static helper method: `myResult = MyContext.GetResultWithInternalUsing();`

Comment: From your perspective, would such improvement make sense to be added to c# one day or does it look like unlikely or bad usage scenario? The second proposition (with out var) looks cleaner from my perspective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use extension method to "simplify" this usage pattern:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static TResult GetThenDispose<TDisposable, TResult>(
        this TDisposable d, 
        Func<TDisposable, TResult> func) 
            where TDisposable : IDisposable {

        using (d) {
            return func(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
string myResult = new myDisposableType().GetThenDispose(c => c.GetResult());
```

Comment: It looks like the most compact, generic and readable proposition. I would just name it in a way that explicitly says that the object is disposed after usage. i.e. GetThenDispose, GetAndDispose, UsingGetValue or whatever like this.

Comment: @y0uri - Well, "get" is only there because of the specific `func` you put in. You could also use it for example to store data to a file or DB. So you might want to name it `DoThenDispose` or something more general like that.

Comment: @Corak then what would be the benefit of using this instead of a normal using? Returning a value is the point.

Comment: @y0uri yes, GetThenDispose looks fine for me

Comment: @y0uri - You could use it for example to mainly store something and additionally/optionally get an error or success code back. Calling the method `Get...` would put too much emphasis on the return value in that case imho. Your mileage may vary, though.

Comment: @Corak you're righ, but still, I don't like the Do.. It suggests a void or result code return. Anyway, for the naming I'll find my way.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no such shortcut. Your original way is right.

You could wrap this in a function if you do it often enough

```
public class Utilities 
{
    public static TReturn GetValueFromUsing<T,TReturn>(Func<T,TReturn> func) where T : IDisposable, new()
    {
        TReturn result = default(TReturn)
        using(var instance = new T())
            result = func(instance);
        return result;
    }
}
```

usage

```
var result = Utilities.GetValueFromUsing<myDisposableType,string>(x => x.GetResult());
```

But man would that be *overkill*.

Answer (score 5):

This is funny, because I started reading *Functional Programming in C#* a couple of days ago, and one of the first examples is along the lines of:

```
public static TResult Using<TDisposable, TResult>(TDisposable disposable, Func<TDisposable, TResult> func) 
    where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
    using (disposable)
    {
        return func(disposable);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 var result = Using(new DbConnection(), x => x.GetResult());
```

Notice that, unlike the other answers posted, this function has absolutely no responsibility but get the result of `func`, regardless of `TDisposable`.

Comment: All well and good, but as a principle, if you creat the object you should dispose it. If you dont then the thing that created it should.

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, I'm aware of that, just wanted to present that the idea exists in a functional way

Comment: How about instead of `TDisposable disposable` we have `Func<TDisposable> getDisposable` and use it like `var result = Using(() => new DbConnection(), x => x.GetResult());`?

Comment: @Corak That's, in fact, the second or third exercise of the book :)

Comment: FUNctional programming is funny. Nothing seems to actually really *do* anything. It's just delegates passed around, building a huge structure of dominos, with the app root pushing the first block.

Answer (score 1):

The `using` instruction cannot be used as r-value, and therefore there is no way to *assign* a value from it.

However, there is a special case to this, and you can use it where convenient: You can *return* a result from inside the `using` block.

```
int F(int arg)
{
    using (disposable = GetObj())
    {
       return disposable.Calculate(arg);
    }
}
```

This form is often communicating the purpose better than a local variable assignment. You can even turn it into a template method, where the method would apply the `using` construct and then call a strategy and return its result.

```
class Useful<TDisposable> where TDisposable : IDisposable
{
    private Func<TDisposable> Factory { get; }
    public Useful(Func<TDisposable> factory) 
    {
       this.Fatory = factory;
    }

    public TResult SafeDo<TResult>(Func<TDisposable, TResult> operation) 
    {
       using (TDisposable obj = this.Factory())
       {
           return operation(obj);
       }
    }
}
```

This class is completely reusable and its single responsibility is to ensure that disposable components are disposed on use. Instead of working directly with a disposable class, you can wrap it into this wrapper class and consume it that way and you'll have a strict lifetime control over the disposable objects:

```
void Worker(Useful<MyDisposableClass> wrapper)
{
    int arg = 5;
    wrapper.SafeDo(disp => disp.Calculate(arg);
}
```

In this piece of code, the `disp` object would be constructed and disposed correctly. A concrete argument that would be required by the operation `arg` is taken from the closure.